# Kivy / pygame touch event CPU time

Tags: python, pygame, kivy

I think I must have some kind of loop going on in my Kivy code - even with a really simple touch event, the processor shoots up to several hundred percent. Is there any way of understanding why from cprofile? I've put the top section here: https://paste.ee/p/Bdvv8

*Note: I generated the cprofile output by running the app for a few minutes and triggering loads of touch events during that time*